# Panel theme reverts to standard GNOME in indicator area

Tags: 11.04, unity, themes, panel

My top bar looks normal up to the point where the indicators appear. The theme and icons don't apply there and it looks like this[image]

I don't know why but that little part of the bar with indicators never changes to the look it's supposed to. Can anyone tell me how I can fix this?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reapplying the theme?

Comment: like 50 times and nothing

Comment: it hasnt bein with this theme only,its bein with all of them and they were from gnome and of the ubuntu software center